# How to pretty print a scala type?

Tags: scala

I want to show the user a value, a simplified type and the original type.

I'm using [pprint](http://lihaoyi.github.io/upickle-pprint/pprint/) library for the value and `scala.Manifest` for the type.

```
def render[T](a: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): (String, String, String) =
  (pprint(a), simplify(m), m.toString)
```

I want to implement this `simplify` function.

It would remove common imports

```
def simplify[T](m: Manifest[T]): String =
  m.toString
   .replaceAll("scala.", "")
   .replaceAll("scala.collection.immutable.", "")
   .replaceAll("scala.collection.mutable.", "")
   .replaceAll("java.lang.", "")
```

but `m.toString` has the following drawback

- desugars functions, `(Int, Int) => Int` becomes `scala.Function2[Int, Int, Int]`
- desugars tuples, `(Int, Int)` becomes `scala.Tuple2[Int, Int]`

Answer (score 0):

type pretty print is implemented in ammonite-repl with `TPrint[T]`

`libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite-repl" % "0.5.4" cross CrossVersion.full`

```
import ammonite.repl.frontend.TPrint
val config = pprint.Config.Defaults.PPrintConfig
def render[T](a: T)(implicit tp: TPrint[T], m: Manifest[T]): (String, String, String) =
  (pprint(a), tp.render(config), m.toString)
```